# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule() cannot visit lower url levels

Tags: wp-query, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a post type called "shop" and added query variables and a rewrite rule.

```
// Adds query vars for shop post type
function gtp_add_shop_query_vars( $vars ) {

    $vars[] = 'shop-category';
    $vars[] = 'width';
    $vars[] = 'height';
    return $vars;       
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'gtp_add_shop_query_vars' );

// Adds rewrite rules for shop post type
function gtp_add_shop_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^shop/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$', 'index.php?shop-category=$matches[1]&width=$matches[2]&height=$matches[3]', 'top' );
}
add_action('init', 'gtp_add_shop_rewrite_rules', 10, 0);
```

With this rules I can visit now:

https://www.example.com/shop/product/80cm/100cm/

But if I want to visit:

- https://www.example.com/shop/product/80cm/
- https://www.example.com/shop/product/

the regex does not match anymore and the page will not be found.

What do I need to do to be able to enter all the levels of the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem as follows:

```
// Adds rewrite rules for shop post type
function gtp_add_shop_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^shop/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$', 'index.php?shop-category=$matches[1]&width=$matches[2]&height=$matches[3]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^shop/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$', 'index.php?shop-category=$matches[1]&width=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^shop/([^/]*)$', 'index.php?shop-category=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
add_action('init', 'gtp_add_shop_rewrite_rules', 10, 0);
```